# Observable.FromAsyncPattern & UdpClient C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udpclient, unirx

i want to be able to use reactive to receive udp packages asynchronously.
i've written this block of code.

```
udpServer = new UdpClient(20000);
remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 20000);

var read = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(udpServer.BeginReceive, t => udpServer.EndReceive(t, ref remoteEP));
```

then i consume this function and store the IObservable resulting.

```
reader = read()
       .Do(s =>
       {
           Logs.Add(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s));
       })
       .DoOnError(ex => status = ex.Message; );
```

when i subscribe finally, the operation happens only once then observer gets disposed with on complete.

**and here comes my question** : is there a way to make this code work continuously ? 
to receive the "DO" operation every time new logs are received?

sidebar: just wonder whats the point with Observable.FromAsyncPattern if i can't reuse it, im better off statically typing 2 methods for the begin and end instead of getting the overhead of more instances of classes that needs disposal later.

-im also open for whole other different options except using TPL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 20000)),
            udpServer =>
                Observable
                    .Defer(() =>
                        Observable
                            .FromAsync(() => udpServer.ReceiveAsync()))
                    .Repeat());
```

You need to manage the `IDispose` resources using `.Using` and you need to `.Repeat` the call to `FromAsync`.

The `FromAsyncPattern` is now obsolete.

---

If you need to use the obsolete `FromAsyncPattern` do this:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new UdpClient(20000),
            udpServer =>
                Observable
                    .Defer(() =>
                        Observable
                            .FromAsyncPattern(udpServer.BeginReceive, t => udpServer.EndReceive(t, ref remoteEP)))
                    .Repeat());
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I mean, as a guide or something. The book I read years ago (Introduction to Rx) didn't even mention some of the API you are using in that manner so I assume it is pretty new.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - No, except for the `.FromAsync` call, this has all been there since 1.0.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229585(v=vs.103).aspx) [Defer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229160(v=vs.103).aspx) [Repeat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.repeat(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I must not have looked hard enough.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am still looking for a way to use the obsolete call since im in unity ,using .net 3.5 .

Comment: @jurasans - The code still applies. Just replace the `.FromAsync` with your `.FromAsyncPattern`.

Comment: ok ok im impressed but i dont have Observable.using, can i use something else instead? :)

Comment: @jurasans - How can you not have `Observable.Using`? It's in the `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace since version 1.0.

Comment: @jurasans - I didn't realise that this existed. The tag `system.reactive` isn't valid then.

Answer (score 0):

This is because observers work on a given collection. The collection returned from the `BeginReceive` is different from calling it again. With the code you've shown, I'm not surprised it only works once. You need a consistent buffer be supplied to `BeginReceive` and then subscribe an observer to that buffer for it trigger every time. That is, the buffer needs to be the same instance between calls.

Comment: i would love an example of what you mean. im trying to do what you said but i cant seem to nail it .